# Creating a popup with UIView when a cell is tapped in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a tableview and if a cell is tapped on the tableview, I want to create a UIView to pop up over the tableview and display the contents in the tableview cell. I want to add the code in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` so that the UIView is opened when I select a row. I just need to know how to create a popup with UIView. I couldn't find any source which helped me out with this. A bit of explanation on how to do this will be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1**

create one `UIView` set the frame as `View.bounds` at the same time add the `Tap gesture` for hide function.

**Step-2**

for present the view on click, use

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
    yourView.alpha = 1.0
})
```

**Step-3**

on hide

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
    yourView.alpha = 0.0
})
```

finally if you want to hide use `hidden` or `removefromsuperview`

Answer (score 2):

First add `let vw = UIView()`, then try this

```
    vw.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 0, 0)
    vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(vw)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

        self.vw.frame = CGRectMake(75, 75, 300, 300)

    }, completion: nil)
```

First create a UIView, and set its X and Y point(150), then width and height (300). I just simply add a background color to show that it is really there. Then the `animatedWithDuration` part is to reset the frame so it looks like pop up.

add this if you want the view behind become darker.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
```

As for touching background view to close the pop up view. You need a tap gesture recogniser, and function for it

```
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tap.delegate = self
    tap.addTarget(self, action: "tapped")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

then for its function

```
    func tapped(){
       vw.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: I want it to appear as a pop up with an animation. It should also be dismissible when I touch anywhere outside the view. I think I can manage the dismissing part. I need to add an animation when the view pops up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IOS 8 or later you can just create UIView in the new UIViewController with setting attribute ModalPresentationStyle with value UIModalPresentationStyle. Something like this in you didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
var popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCategory") as UIViewController
var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,600)
popover.delegate = self
popover.sourceView = self.view
popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)

self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Seeing the first line I presume that you're asking me to add a new viewcontroller in the story board with the storyboard ID "NewCategory"? If that's not what you meant, to which view Controller does the storyboard ID "NewCategory" belong to?

Comment: You can create popup only with new UIviewcontroller. You can create it in storyboard or another way you like